# Widget rebuilding even after passing the same key

Tags: flutter

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {})),
      body: FooPage(key: ValueKey(0)),
    );
  }
}

class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FooPage({super.key});
  final int _number = math.Random().nextInt(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('number = $_number');
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Each time you click the FAB, the `number` prints a new value. But as I'm already passing same `key` to the `FooPage`, why is it the `MainScreen` creates a new `FooPage` instance from scratch instead of using the existing one (with key `0`)?

---

**NOTE:**

Please don't post answers to use `const FooPage()` after declaring a `const` constructor in the `FooPage` or assign `FooPage` to a final instance field in the `MainScreen` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure understand your issue!. You want FooPage not rebuild every time you call setState in MainScreen?

Comment: @eamirho3ein No, it can rebuild (no issue there). But the value of `_number` should be same each time the `MainScreen` rebuilds otherwise what would be the point of assigning the `key` to the `FooPage`. Please check the edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a key to a StatelessWidget doesn't make it stateful (remebering the random int).

I.e. the framework will still dispose and rebuild it as a new instance when deemed necessary.